# Dual-booting Windows 2000 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

Win98 is on partition 1, 2000 is on 2, Ubuntu is to be downloaded on 1 = instal on C:  W98 is history [no more updates], I've striped it down to just be a backup save for D:
my 2000 is soooo updated that to re-install everything is not an option, I'm sure my install disc is soooo dated that I won't be able to re-update.
on C: with Win98 i use boot.ini to dual boot = i want to dual boot 2000-Ubuntu.
will Ubuntu and a 'boot.ini' live together after I install Ubuntu on C:?

Comment: Is it a pre-release of windows '98?  Windows 2098 perhaps?

Comment: scare of my own thought there ;)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understand you right. If you want to install Ubuntu into the win98 partition and leaving it a win98 partition as it is at the moment.

If that is correct, you can use [wubi.exe](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide) to install Ubuntu just into the win98 file system. You can find the wubi.exe file at the [Ubuntu download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer).

If you want to replace the win98 partition, you can just install Ubuntu from the live CD and choose the first partition to be replaced by the Ubuntu installation during the installation process.

Comment: Also, Grub2 will overwrite the boot.ini, but will give you the choice between whether to boot from Windows 2000, or Ubuntu...

Comment: wait, does wubi even work in windows 98?

Answer (score 0):

grub 2 will add windows 2000 to the list of boot choices from past experience i dual booted windows 2000 just make sure you install on the right disk partition...

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, what exactly is your question? Dual boot Windows 2000 with Ubuntu and replace Windows 98 with the Ubuntu system? If that's the case just use an Ubuntu Live CD or USB and install over that particular partition replacing it with Ubuntu Linux. The process will overwrite your boot.ini file via Grub2 but there will be a boot menu allowing you to choose which partition/OS to boot into.